# Unloading plugin fails after changing toolbar location

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, toolbar

For a Qgis plugin I want to make a toolbar with additional buttons, which I want to dock on the vertically on left side beneath the add layers buttons 
I made the toolbar with in the a :

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar("My tools")   
        self.iface.addToolBar(self.toolbar, area=Qt.LeftToolBarArea)
```

To unload the plugin I used:

```
    def unload(self):
        del self.toolbar
```

The toolbar is in the proper location, however when I unload the plugin it does not delete the toolbar. And when I reload it it creates an extra instance. So, I appear to have no way to unload the toolbar. I tried assigning a variable to the second addToolBar function but it returns None. Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following to remove the toolbar before deleting it:

```
def unload(self):
    self.iface.mainWindow().removeToolBar( self.toolbar )
    del self.toolbar
```

Comment: @StefVerdonk - Most welcome, glad it worked :)